# Parse XML using DOM in android

Tags: java, android, xml, xml-parsing

Hi i want to parse XML and display list based on selection of user

my xml is looking like this

[image]

below is my code

```
      try {
            XMLParser parser = new XMLParser();
            Document doc = parser.getDomElement(xml); // getting DOM element
            NodeList n1 = doc.getElementsByTagName("company");

            // looping through all item nodes <item>
            for (int i = 0; i < n1.getLength(); i++) {
                // creating new HashMap
                Element e = (Element) n1.item(i);

                System.out.println("name node "+parser.getValue(e, "name"));
            }
```

by this way i am getting the output like

```
  Company ABC
  Company XYZ
```

of Companies list

but
      i would write code like

```
        NodeList n1 = doc.getElementsByTagName("province"); 
        // looping through all item nodes <item>
            for (int i = 0; i < n1.getLength(); i++) {
                // creating new HashMap
                Element e = (Element) n1.item(i);

                System.out.println("name node "+parser.getValue(e, "name"));
            }
```

i am getting list of province name

```
   Alberta
   Ontario
   New York
   Florida
```

but it should work like this

when i select Company ABC

only two provision list should display

```
       Alberta
       Ontario
```

not should all display can any body help me how to rewrite my code

Comment: Should i have use another XML method or with do like this way!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```
        XMLParser parser = new XMLParser();
        Document doc = parser.getDomElement(xml); // getting DOM element
        NodeList n1 = doc.getElementsByTagName("company");

        // looping through all item nodes <item>
        for (int i = 0; i < n1.getLength(); i++) {
            Element e = (Element) n1.item(i);
            System.out.println("name node "  +parser.getValue(e, "name"));
            NodeList children = e.getChildNodes();
            for (int j = 0; j < children.getLength(); j++) {
                 Node child = children.item(j);
                 if (child.getNodeName().equalsIgnoreCase("province")) {
                      System.out.println("name node " + parser.getValue((Element)child, "name"));
                 }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Node child = nodes.item(i); what is nodes?? is is children?

Comment: Sorry it was wrong, it should be `Node child = children.item(j);`

Comment: ya i have done tat but still getting error on parser.getValue(child, "name"));

Comment: The method getValue(Element, String) in the type XMLParser is not applicable for the arguments (Node, 
 String)

Comment: that should be `parser.getValue((Element)child, "name")`. Sorry I wrote this code out of my head, never compiled it. It should give you an idea, and minor problems like these you should be able to fix yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Use `Node.getChildNodes()` over the "company" nodes. Then, to get the child province nodes, compare by name. Example:

```
    XMLParser parser = new XMLParser();
    Document doc = parser.getDomElement(xml); // getting DOM element
    NodeList n1 = doc.getElementsByTagName("company");

    // looping through all item nodes <item>
    for (int i = 0; i < n1.getLength(); i++) {
        Node companyNode = n1.item(i);
        NodeList childNodes = companyNode.getChildNodes();
        // Here we're getting child nodes inside the company node.
        // Only direct childs will be returned (name and province)  

        for (int j = 0; j < childNodes.getLength(); j++) {
            Node childNode = childNodes.item(j);
            if("province".equalsIgnoreCase(childNode.getName())){
                //Do something with province
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: can u explain with example please

Answer (score 1):

Try the following code:

```
public class MainActivity  extends Activity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    /** Create a new layout to display the view */
    LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(this);
    layout.setOrientation(1);

    /** Create a new textview array to display the results */
    TextView name[];
    TextView website[];
    TextView category[];

    try {

        URL url = new URL(
                "http://xyz.com/aa.xml");
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = db.parse(new InputSource(url.openStream()));
        doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

        NodeList nodeList = doc.getElementsByTagName("item");

        /** Assign textview array lenght by arraylist size */
        name = new TextView[nodeList.getLength()];
        website = new TextView[nodeList.getLength()];
        category = new TextView[nodeList.getLength()];

        for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {

            Node node = nodeList.item(i);

            name[i] = new TextView(this);
            website[i] = new TextView(this);
            category[i] = new TextView(this);

            Element fstElmnt = (Element) node;
            NodeList nameList = fstElmnt.getElementsByTagName("name");
            Element nameElement = (Element) nameList.item(0);
            nameList = nameElement.getChildNodes();
            name[i].setText("Name = "
                    + ((Node) nameList.item(0)).getNodeValue());

            NodeList websiteList = fstElmnt.getElementsByTagName("website");
            Element websiteElement = (Element) websiteList.item(0);
            websiteList = websiteElement.getChildNodes();
            website[i].setText("Website = "
                    + ((Node) websiteList.item(0)).getNodeValue());

            category[i].setText("Website Category = "
                    + websiteElement.getAttribute("category"));

            layout.addView(name[i]);
            layout.addView(website[i]);
            layout.addView(category[i]);

        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("XML Pasing Excpetion = " + e);
    }

    /** Set the layout view to display */
    setContentView(layout);

}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The getElementsBytagName called on the document object will always return the list of **all** the nodes with the given tag name in the whole document. Instead, filter out the single company element you are interested in, and then call getElementsByTagName on **it**. E.g.

```
Element companyEl = doc.getElementById(desiredCompanyId);
if (companyEl != null) { // always good to check
    NodeList n1 = companyEl.getElementsByTagName("province");

    // your code here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with this code

for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {

```
        Node node = nodeList.item(i);

        name[i] = new TextView(this);
        website[i] = new TextView(this);
        category[i] = new TextView(this);

        Element fstElmnt = (Element) node;
        NodeList nameList = fstElmnt.getElementsByTagName("name");
        Element nameElement = (Element) nameList.item(0);
        nameList = nameElement.getChildNodes();
        name[i].setText("Name = "
                + ((Node) nameList.item(0)).getNodeValue());

        NodeList websiteList = fstElmnt.getElementsByTagName("website");
        Element websiteElement = (Element) websiteList.item(0);
        websiteList = websiteElement.getChildNodes();
        website[i].setText("Website = "
                + ((Node) websiteList.item(0)).getNodeValue());

        category[i].setText("Website Category = "
                + websiteElement.getAttribute("category"));

        layout.addView(name[i]);
        layout.addView(website[i]);
        layout.addView(category[i]);

    }
```