# Android xml parsing based on selection of item

Tags: java, android, xml, dom, xml-parsing

I want to parse xml that display list like below

```
 Company ABC
 Company XYZ
```

When user select **Company ABC** it's sub content should be display like below

```
 Alberta
 Ontario
```

Again select Alberta

```
Calgary
```

Again select Calgary

```
 CFGM- Country
 Cddr- news talk
```

So on and on it's sub category should be displayed

I have tried code which is in below link but it is not working for me can any body help me **using any xml parsing method** to solve this issue, in below link i have used DOM method but still not working....

[Parse XML using DOM in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14706751/parse-xml-using-dom-in-android)

the xml is looking like below

[image]

Comment: What have you tried? what went wrong? This seems a pretty standard usage for the DOM Parser.

Comment: see this link i have tried in DOM but it is not working as i want http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14706751/parse-xml-using-dom-in-android

Comment: hard to help with no code, Log... and please give a text version or url of your xml file.