# Parsing XML(Nodes)

Tags: java, android, xml, parsing, nodelist

I have a small problem that in [this](http://imageshack.com/a/img838/9606/wyjf.png) XML 
I want to get the title and description from Rss I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14706751/parse-xml-using-dom-in-android) solution

and use this function

```
RssObject Value = new RssObject();

public void getTagRss(String URL) {
    XMLParser parser = new XMLParser();
    String xml = getXml(URL);
    Document doc = parser.getDomElement(xml);
    NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName(Rss_key); // Site tag Name
    for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++) {
        Element e = (Element) nl.item(i);
        NodeList children = e.getChildNodes();
        Log.i(TAG, "Children length: " + children.getLength());
        for (int j = 0; j < children.getLength(); j++) {
            Node child = children.item(j);
            // name child value
            if (child.getNodeName().equalsIgnoreCase(Item_key)) {
                // name child value
                Value.Title = parser.getValue(e, Title_key);
                Value.Desc = parser.getValue(e, Desc_key);
                Gen_Obj.Rsslist2.add(Value);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and the output is [this](http://imageshack.com/a/img835/6656/1juy.png)

that repeat first item twice where give me the length of children is 5 
what is the wrong in my function 
thanks

Comment: taka look at this https://developers.google.com/feed/ and this https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/

Comment: but can you say what wrong with my code ?? :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it will be like

```
public void getTagRss(String URL) {
    XMLParser parser = new XMLParser();
    String xml = getXml(URL);
    Document doc = parser.getDomElement(xml);
    NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName(Rss_key); // Site tag Name
    for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++) {
        Element e = (Element) nl.item(i);
        NodeList children = e.getElementsByTagName(Item_key);
        for (int j = 0; j < children.getLength(); j++) {
            Element C1 = (Element) children.item(j);
            RssObject Value = new RssObject();
            Value.Title = parser.getValue(C1, Title_key);
            Value.Desc = parser.getValue(C1, Desc_key);
            Gen_Obj.Rsslist2.add(Value);
        }
    }
}
```

thanks :D